# Display Azure DevOps pipeline variables inside my code

Tags: variables, configuration, azure-devops, display, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

Before, I was displaying my product version with :

`@string.Format("v{0}", ViewContext.Controller.GetType().Assembly.GetName().Version)`

where the version was stored in the AssemblyInfo.cs like so :

`[assembly: AssemblyVersion("2.2.1.0")]`

and the result was "v2.2.1"

Now, I'm using CI/CD with Azure DevOps and I'd like to display the $(Release.ReleaseName) instead of the AssemblyVersion.

How can I do that? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

tag\update the assemblyinfo.cs with the `$(release.releasename)` variable value during the build. there is a special task for that, as far as I recall, something like this: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=richardfennellBM.BM-VSTS-Versioning-Task

or just create a script that would do that for you

Comment: Thank you for you suggestion, I'll download the extension and see what if offers. However, I let the subject unresolved until I've tested it or someone else suggests something more Microsoft-ish :p

Answer (score 0):

> Display Azure DevOps pipeline variables inside my code

AFAIK, there is no out of box to way to update the AssemblyVersion by the value the `$(Release.ReleaseName)`.

As workaround, just like 4c74356b41 pointed out, you could use the [Assembly Info](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bleddynrichards.Assembly-Info-Task) task to update the `AssemblyInfo.cs`:

[image]

[image]

Note:

- Since you need use this task in the release pipeline, you need change the default value in the **Source folder** to `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)`.
- The Release name format need match the [Semantic Versioning Specification (SemVer)](https://semver.org/spec/v1.0.0.html)

Hope this helps.